# How to #include <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h> in Xcode 10

Tags: xcode, header-files

Xcode 10 has changed the method for searching for header files. Specifically, it gives the warning:

> Traditional headermap style is no longer supported; please migrate to
>   using separate headermaps and set 'ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS' to NO.

So, having done that, it's then necessary to juggle around some other (mainly third-party) paths in the projects search paths in order for them to be found.

However, I'm running into a problem when I need to include `CoreGraphics.h`. (It's not a question of if I need to, but how to do it.) It's buried deep in the framework tree — something I thought the whole "headermap" idea was supposed to solve.

What's the correct method to include framework header(s) now?

Note: The source files are either .cpp or .mm (either C++ or Objective-C++).

Comment: Have you tried setting `ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS` to `NO`, as suggested?

Answer (score -1):

Objective-C:

```
#import "CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h"
```

Comment: `#include <file.h>` are for system includes and `#include "file.h"` are for local/project includes.